# Short story about a photo restoration specialist who can travel back in time to the day a photo was taken

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, time-travel

This was a short story, told in the third person. Written in English. I first read it in a library book, sometime during the 1980s, *probably* no later than 1986. (I lived in Indiana at the time.) I'm pretty sure it was in an anthology of stories by various authors. No telling how old the story already was when I read it; nor how old that particular book was. I've never run across the story in any other volume, which makes me pretty sure it wasn't by such big names as Isaac Asimov, Arthur C. Clarke, Roger Zelazny, etc. The plot was very simple; I'm tempted to say "downright corny by modern standards." (But I restrain myself.)

**Plot Points**

1. The protagonist is a bachelor who is a trained photographer. He does a lot of restoration work on faded old photographs, decades old. A typical client might say, "This is all I have left to remember Grandma and Grandpa by," and then the protagonist would try to make it look more crisp. The author gave some technical details about how this was done; enough to make me think the author actually knew something about the chemicals and tools of pre-digital photography. (Not that I would have known if the author flubbed some of the details.)
2. Gradually, the protagonist begins to have moments when he seems to be "living within the photograph" -- i.e. standing off to one side of the scene in question, seeing the relevant people in full color, hearing them talk to each other, feeling the wind on his face, etc. The first time this happens, it wears off pretty quickly. He is alone in his studio, with no witnesses, and is keenly aware of the possibility that he simply dreamed or hallucinated the entire thing.
3. Nonetheless, he decides to let this glimpse into the past inspire him. In other words, he uses his vivid memories of that brief visit to guide his restoration work on certain details of clothing and facial features and so forth, in the photograph which triggered the event. Afterwards, the current client is satisfied with the results. (Of course, the photographer doesn't say a word about having slipped back in time to get a good look at Grandma and Grandpa in their prime; the client might not understand.)
4. Eventually, while staring at another old photograph, the protagonist ends up at some sort of "church picnic" or similarly wholesome social event, in a certain small town in the USA, around the early years of the 20th Century, and begins to strike up a conversation with a sweet and charming young lady. (The protagonist is a lonely man with no wife or girlfriend in the "modern world," you understand.)
5. In the end, he deliberately goes "back into" that photograph for another visit -- or perhaps he plunged into another photo of some of the same people when he encounters it later; I'm not sure. It is at least implied, if not stated outright, that he can and will stay in that past era permanently, supporting himself with his detailed knowledge of photographic techniques, and (presumably) will marry the charming young lady after a lengthy courtship process.

Does anyone recognize it from the description?

**P.S.** As I look back at what I just typed, it strikes me that when I summarize the plot this way, it ends up sounding like the sort of unabashedly nostalgic thing that Ray Bradbury sometimes wrote -- but I'm almost certain it *wasn't* one of his. For one thing, I don't remember ever running across it in any of the collections of Bradbury's short stories which I've enjoyed at various times since then. And I don't think the writing style was reminiscent of Bradbury's. Plus the fact that I'd *probably* have remembered his name was attached to it; I believe I'd already read *The Martian Chronicles* and some of his other works before I ever read this story about a photographer.

Comment: Sounds like some of Jack Finney's themes. Off the top of my head the short story "I'm Scared" and the novel "Time and Again" feature the same sort of time travel you're describing.

Comment: sliiiiiightly similar (a photographer and time travel) to this modern Outer Limits episode, but I can't find any indication it was based on a short story: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettysburg_(The_Outer_Limits)

Comment: @user888379 I think the only Finney novel I've read is *The Bodysnatchers* (not very good), but after looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudolph_Fentz I know I've read "I'm Scared." I recognize the plot, and it was published in a Heinlein-edited anthology *Tomorrow, the Stars,* which I've read. (Heck, that book included a Simak story I once asked about in a story-id question.) But I don't think I've ever read any books collecting lots of Finney's short stories, so I have no idea whether the one I've described here might be lurking somewhere among his published works.

Comment: @NKCampbell Interesting. I never really got into any of the "Outer Limits" stuff; I've only seen maybe two episodes of the newer series. For what it's worth, I'm sure the story I described did not have any battles or assassinations taking place onstage; nor do I think anything so violent was mentioned as happening elsewhere at the same time as the church picnic. If it were during the Civil War or the Spanish-American War or WWI, the war should have been weighing on the minds of every family that had a son in uniform who might die on the front lines. So the resemblance is probably coincidental.

Comment: @user888379 I made one small mistake (irrelevant to answering my question about the time-traveling photographer). *Tomorrow, the Stars* didn't contain a Clifford Simak story I once asked for help in identifying; it contained a William Tenn story I once asked for help in identifying. My memory had garbled the details of which story-id answer had reminded me of that old anthology. I should have checked before I made that offhand remark.

Comment: @Lorendiac Funny that you should mention a collection of Finney's short stories: ["About Time"](https://www.simonandschuster.com/books/About-Time/Jack-Finney/9780684848662). After I posted my comment yesterday, I remembered "The Third Level" which is another trip to the well.

Comment: I was hoping it was Finney's "The Face in the Photograph" when I saw that title, but no. http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57642

Comment: It makes me think of a Richard Matheson story but I'm very vague on the details

Comment: @DannyMcG I just now looked at Matheson's Wikipedia page. I think I've only read two of his novels, but there's a ton of shorter stories listed, and I have no idea how many of those I may have read in one anthology or another. (I don't believe I have ever read a book that was simply collecting a bunch of stories all written by Richard Matheson.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I remember reading a story like that in an anthology, and after much googling, I think it's *[Christopher Frame](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1216658)* by [Nancy C Swoboda](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?148694). It was published in the anthology *[Thrillers, Chillers and Killers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?339300)* edited by [Helen Hoke](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?10830). The only reference to the plot of the story that I've been able to find is a quote from [Atomic Junkshop](http://atomicjunkshop.com/alfred-hitchcock-presents-breaking-scream-barrier/) about the content of another anthology *Alfred Hitchcock Presents: Breaking the Scream Barrier (Stories to be Read With the Lights On, Vol. 2)*:

> Nancy C. Swoboda’s “Christopher Frame” is a sweet little tale that could have been one of the more sentimental Twilight Zone stories, with a man who creates oil painting recreations of old photographs for clients, and how he discovers a method to get the details correct when working from the old sepia toned pictures.

Some more plot details that may jog your memory:

- The protagonist knew when he was about to return to the present by hearing the increasing volume of the ticking of a timer that he had set to time a photographic process.
- The protagonist performed an experiment to see if he could bring objects from the past to the present - he broke a decorative wooden ball from the top of a railing and kept hold of it while he returned to the present. That experiment was a success.
- At the end, his intent was to bring the woman in the photograph with whom he had fallen in love back to the present. That failed, and he remained in the past.
- In the final scene, detectives were investigating the protagonist's disappearance, and one of them notices that a person in an old photograph looks identical to the protagonist.

Comment: I think you're right. Back in the 1980s I lived near a library that had a bunch of those "Alfred Hitchcock Presents" collections on the shelves, so I could have read it there. (Strengthened by the fact that I looked at Atomic Junkshop's comments, and at least 2 of the other stories he summarizes sound *very familiar.*) So I'm accepting your answer. I didn't remember that the photographer tried to bring the girl to the present with him, nor that the cops were seen investigating his disappearance at the very end, but I'm willing to believe it was all part of the same story's plot.

Answer (score -2):

Christopher Frame by Nancy C. Swoboda

Found in two anthologies:
Alfred Hithcock’s “Stories to be read with the lights on”
“Thrillers, Chillers & Killers” by Helen Hoke

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please note that this answer has already been provided and accepted.  Please don't post duplicate answers; you might want to take the [tour].